# How to determine 'Output bit depth' of the libx264 library in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, video-encoding, x264

According to the [x264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide), the `crf` scale depends on whether x264 is 8-bit or 10-bit. Supposedly `x264 --help` shows the `Output bit depth`. But on Windows `ffmpeg -h full` doesn't say anything about `Output bit depth` and the `crf` scale option is described as `from -1 to FLT_MAX`. How can I check if my ffmpeg is using 8-bit or 10-bit version of the libx264 library?

**EDIT**

As the answer suggested, if the bit depth is 8 and `crf` higher than `51` is used then ffmpeg will automatically adjust the `crf` value to be `51` - the highest possible. So it's enough to check the output from ffmpeg to determine the bit depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help is from `x264` itself and not under `ffmpeg`. In linux distributions the `x264` being in the path allows you to type `x264 --help`.

In windows you might want to `cd` to the `x264` installed folder and type `x264.exe --help`, but I don't work on windows for ffmpeg so I can't say surely.

As noted in the reference you provide, most distributions are 8 bit. Why don't you use a `crf` value of `63` and see if it throws an error- then you most probably have the 8 bit distributuion.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's from x264, that's why I mentioned it. On Windows ffmpeg is not installed with x264, so I can't cd to its folder. On Windows ffmpeg uses the libx264 library and there is no separate x264 executable. If I could use x264 to query the output bit depth then there would be no question to ask.

Comment: Can you try a `crf` of 63 and see what it says?

Comment: That worked, thanks. ffmpeg didn't throw any errors but the crf has been automatically adjusted to 51 (the max value for 8-bit depth)

Answer (score 1):

A different method would be to encode a low-quality test video with `ffmpeg` (using a duration limit and the "ultrafast" preset, for example) and then interrogate the resulting MP4 with `ffprobe` to determine the actual bit depth of the video stream. The command to run would be `ffprobe -show_streams /path/to/video.mp4` and the field to look for in the output is "bits_per_raw_sample=8". You can also set the output format to be JSON by adding the `-print_format json` option.